# I am getting an error with this on load ribbon tab code

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using this code, but i'm receiving an error when excel tries to load it, works fine on excel 365 but on excel 2007 throws error:

```
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">

Public Rib As IRibbonUI
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)

    Set Rib = ribbon

End Sub

Sub startHereConfigure()

    Rib.ActivateTab "Configure"

End Sub
```

calling it here:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    startHereConfigure '<<<<-getting object doesn't support this property or method
end sub
```

Comment: I think `ActivateTab` is not available in Excel 2007

Comment: I've tried ActivateTabMso as well with same error. I need it to work for both 2007 n office 365

Comment: Both methods are not availabe in 2007. You will have them AFAIK with 2010 and onwards.

Comment: AFAIK? whats that?

Comment: Are you a newbie to the internet :-) AFAIK=As far as I know. Anyway, you can remove the AFAIK in my comment. `ActivateTab` and `ActivateTabMso`are availabe with 2010 and later.

Comment: @Franz: Why should this be a duplicate? I do not think so at all.

Comment: how can i get it to work on 2007 @Storax

Comment: Update to Excel 2010

Comment: I am sorry, I already retracted the flag.

Comment: @ThisGuyJustNeedsHelp: Or you try to implemet [this](https://www.rholtz-office.de/ribbonx/ein-beliebiges-tab-aktivieren) code

Comment: This may work in 2007 too: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1052325-activate-ribbon-tab-without-xml-api-calls.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use [`Application.SendKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys) to send <kbd>Alt</kbd> key combinations that can activate the Ribbon tab, but if the code is running in Excel 14.0 or above (2010+), then I'd keep the `ActivateTab` call, which is much more robust.

Since you're getting error 438, I take it that the member call is late-bound (resolved at run-time), otherwise the code wouldn't even compile, let alone run.

And when code is resolved at run-time, you can use conditional logic to make it, well, conditional - verify the `Application.Version`, and branch accordingly:

```
If Application.Version >= 14 Then
    'Excel 2010+
    Rib.ActivateTab "Configure"

    ''or explicitly late-bound:
    'Dim ui As Object
    'Set ui = Rib
    'ui.ActivateTab
Else
    Application.SendKeys "%C" ' assuming "Alt+C" activates the "Configure" tab; tweak accordingly.
End If
```

Comment: you wouldn't happen to know how to turn back on numlock because it turns it off after sendkeys.

Comment: seems like if i don't do anything for excel 2007, it stays at my ribbon since i inserted it before the Home tab.

Comment: I'm confused. Did you verify what the hotkey was for your custom tab, and adjust the `SendKeys` command accordingly?

Comment: Yes i assigned keytip to my ribbon tab then called it using sendkey, but i figured that if i didn't do anything for excel 2007, it still focuses on my ribbon since i insert my ribbon in front of the "Home" tab therefore that is the default focus.